# Unable to get date from string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I Get `DateTime` string from server "8/27/2016 6:56:23 AM"

And I want to fetch **only date** from this string.

```
        NSString *StreamStartDateTime=@"8/27/2016 6:56:23 AM";
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
        NSDate *date1=[dateFormatter dateFromString:StreamStartDateTime];
```

But the problem is I am getting null in date1.

please help me to find out where I am doing wrong.

Comment: dateformatter is wrong

Comment: try this MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"

Comment: @jan i need only date from string not time and other values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like

```
 NSString *StreamStartDateTime=@"8/27/2016 6:56:23 AM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a"]; or use hh:mm:ss a
 NSDate *date1=[dateFormatter dateFromString:StreamStartDateTime];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
 NSString *ssecond=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date1];
  NSDate *finalDate=[dateFormatter dateFromString:ssecond];
```

final output as

[image]

Comment: i want result in NSDate not in string. because i need to compare two dates.

Comment: @MiteshDobareeya - ok you need date in which format like this `yyyyMMdd` or `MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a`

Comment: in yyyyMMdd. only date, also not in string it must be in nsdate.

Comment: add this line thats all   NSDate *finalDate=[dateFormatter dateFromString:ssecond];

Comment: when i print value of date it gives me this output"2016-08-26 18:30:00 +0000". i need only date "2016-08-26".

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong `dateFormat`. Please replace your code with following:

```
NSString *StreamStartDateTime=@"8/27/2016 6:56:23 AM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *date1=[dateFormatter dateFromString:StreamStartDateTime];
```

Comment: this will give me full date and i need only date.

Answer (score 0):

Your date format must be match with your date string.

So If your date string is `8/27/2016 6:56:23 AM` then your format must be `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a`. Then with this format get date from string first like,

```
 NSDate *date=[df dateFromString:StreamStartDateTime];
```

Now, change date formatter in whatever format you want your date say,

```
 [df setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
```

then

```
  NSString *resultDateStr = [df stringFromDate:date];
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try like this

```
NSString *StreamStartDateTime=@"8/27/2016 6:56:23 AM";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *streamStartDate = [formatter dateFromString:StreamStartDateTime];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
NSString *strDate = [formatter stringFromDate:streamStartDate];
NSDate *compDate = [formatter dateFromString:strDate]; // Get date in UTC format
```

Output:

Printing description of strDate:
20160827

Printing description of compDate:
2016-08-26 18:30:00 +0000

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *LiveStreamStartDateTime=@"8/27/2016 6:56:23 AM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *date1=[dateFormatter dateFromString:LiveStreamStartDateTime];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
NSString *fisrtdate=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date1];
NSDate *date11 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:fisrtdate];
```